# Sqlite DB Error - html5sql.js:82 Error: could not prepare statement (1 near ")": syntax error) while processing statment 1:

Tags: jquery, mysql, sqlite

I am new to coding, and am trying to use the local sqlite DB to store data pulled in from an API. I want to pull in the data from the API the first time (e.g. if it doesn't already exist in the local database), but if it already exists in the local database I would like to pull the data from there. I think I'm having an issue with ansynchrony, so the sql table is not even created before I'm attempting to load it with data. I've tried refactoring my code to try and ensure the table is created first before any data is loaded, but nothing is working. Any help would be appreciated!

```
(function(module) {
  // Permit constructor
  function Market (opts) {
    for (keys in opts) {
      this[keys] = opts[keys];
    }
  }

  Market.all = [];

  Market.getData = function() {
    webDB.execute('SELECT * FROM marketdata', function(rows) {
      if (rows.length) {
        console.log('Market.getData: inside if');
        Market.all = rows;
      } else {
        console.log('Market.getData: inside else');
        $.get('https://data.seattle.gov/resource/3c4b-gdxv.json',
        function(data) {
          Market.all = data;
          if (!rows.length) {
            Market.all.forEach(function(singleMarket) {
              var market = new Market(singleMarket);
              market.insertPermit();
            });
          }
        });
      }
    });
  };

  Market.createTable = function(next) {
    console.log('inside Market.createTable');
    webDB.execute(
      'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS marketdata (' +
        'id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, ' +
        'address VARCHAR(255), ' +
        'city_feature VARCHAR(255);'

    );
    Market.getData();
  };

  Market.prototype.insertPermit = function () {
    webDB.execute(
      [
        {
          'sql': 'INSERT INTO markettdata(address, city_feature) VALUES (?, ?);',
          'data': [this.address, this.city_feature],
        }
      ]
    );
  };

  Market.createTable();

  module.Market = Market;
})(window);
```

Comment: Figured it out-- it was missing a parenthesis after the webDB call in createTable function, so the table was never being created.